# A little question about logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Can we say that $\log _4 (n^2)=\log _2(n)$? If that is the case, then $\displaystyle 2^{\log _4 (n^2)}=n$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Let $x=\log_4n^2=2\log_4n$; then $2^x=2^{2\log_4n}=\left(2^2\right)^{\log_4n}=4^{\log_4n}=n$.

Comment: @bigO: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can also prove this using the fact that $\log_a b =\dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$.

Answer (score 3):

And more generally,
$$
\log_b a = \log_{b^k} (a^k).
$$